# How to query this output in MySQL?

Tags: php, jquery, database, autocomplete

How to query this output in MySQL database? I need the format exactly like this, but I need to retrieve the data from a database instead.

```
$cities = array(
array('city'=>'New York', state=>'NY'),
array('city'=>'Los Angeles', state=>'CA'),
array('city'=>'Chicago', state=>'IL'),
array('city'=>'Houston', state=>'TX'),
array('city'=>'Phoenix', state=>'AZ'),
array('city'=>'Philadelphia', state=>'PA'),
array('city'=>'San Antonio', state=>'TX'),
array('city'=>'Dallas', state=>'TX'),
array('city'=>'San Diego', state=>'CA'),
array('city'=>'San Jose', state=>'CA'),
array('city'=>'Detroit', state=>'MI'),
array('city'=>'San Francisco', state=>'CA'),
array('city'=>'Jacksonville', state=>'FL'),
array('city'=>'Indianapolis', state=>'IN'),
array('city'=>'Austin', state=>'TX'),
array('city'=>'Columbus', state=>'OH'),
array('city'=>'Fort Worth', state=>'TX'),
array('city'=>'Charlotte', state=>'NC'),
array('city'=>'Memphis', state=>'TN'),
array('city'=>'Baltimore', state=>'MD'),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP, this should work

```
$q = $con->query("SELECT city, state FROM your_table");
$new_array = array();
while ($rows = $q->fetch_object()) {
   $new_array[] = $rows;
}
print_r($new_array);
```

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

This will output the exact text you mentioned you wanted out of MySQL.

```
SELECT CONCAT('array(\'city\'=>\'',city, '\',','\'state\'=>\'',state, '\')') 
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: The OP already knows the city, state, and zip. Why would he pull the information he already has?

Comment: According to his question it states "but I need to retrieve the data from a database instead" .... Meaning it doesnt matter if he already has that info. He's trying to get a query string to pull that same data from MYSQL.

Comment: Yes - the data that is there is dummy data. I need to pull actual data from a DB... and place it into the format I have above

Comment: Hey Now i understand your question. Look at my query string now

Comment: @odanny - I sort of expected to see a WHILE loop - no ??

Comment: @Rus .. Nope.. That should should give you the format you asked for, for all the entries in the table you specify..